# How can I revise this to use all of the items in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code in a function I'm trying to revise. This example works on a single item from an existing array named "stream":

```
list = [
    {
        service: 'service1',
        user: stream [0],
        template: {
            posted:HTML1 +  stream[0] + HTML2
        }
    }
],
```

The code originally called for manual entry for the `user` value so I switched to an array since I use the same value(s) elsewhere with $.each for HTML stuff).

The `stream` array can vary in length so I want to avoid manually writing something like this below since I suspect it would need to match the count of `stream` items (could be anywhere from 1 to 50 or more):

```
list = [
    {
        service: 'service1', 
        user: stream [0], 
        template: { 
            posted:HTML1 +  stream[0] + HTML2
        }
    }, 
    { 
        service: 'service1', 
        user: stream [1], 
        template: { 
            posted:HTML1 +  stream[1] + HTML2
        }
    } 
],
```

Thanks for your help and guidance!

PS This is another attempt at this question and hope it is clearer this time. Still learning.

Comment: are you familiar with for loops?

Comment: @Mark Linus thank you for the edit.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help! It seems that my post was clearer this time since I got the solution quickly without any flames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, you want this:

```
var SERVICE = 'service1';

list = jQuery.map(stream, function (item) { 
  return {
    service: SERVICE, 
    user: item, 
    template: { 
        posted:HTML1 +  item + HTML2
    }
  }; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The "service" bit in my example was perhaps misleading. Those values are not indexed to the 'user' or in the 'stream' array. Will test without the index.

Comment: @user1452893 What did you mean? Should all `service` properties have '`service1`' values?

Comment: Sorry, for now, yes all 'service' values are the same. But, that could change as the app evolves where some share "service1" and others share "service2" so I will just make it a var. HTH.

Comment: Yes, we were doing the same thing at the same time. When it gets to the point of not having a static "service" var, I will probably put those values in the 'stream' array.  Your answer works and I updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A solution with just javascript: see Engineer's post for a (simpler) jQuery solution

```
var list = [];

for (var i = 0; i < stream.length; i++) {
    list.push({
        service: 'service1',
        user: stream[i],
        template: {
            posted: HTML1 + stream[i] + HTML2
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is useful for me to see both since it helps my learning.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/xHfDb/

```
$.map(stream, function(item, index) {
        return {
            service: 'service' + index,
            user: item,
            template: {
                posted: HTML1 + item + HTML2
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! See above for 'index" comment. Will test.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the extra effort that helps introduce me to some other stuff illustrated in the jsfiddle. Helps with my learning.